# Sidebar Answer Status

Tags: script, answers, unanswered, linked-questions

### Description:

> As of 1.10 this now also works in Firefox / Greasemonkey.

This is a userscript that modifies the Linked and Related sidebar lists to [show answered status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296537/230261) and other info:

[image]

### Download:

- [Github](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/blob/master/SidebarAnswerStatus.user.js)
- [Github raw](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/raw/master/SidebarAnswerStatus.user.js)

### Features:

- Draws border around "answered" questions (questions with an accepted answer or an answer with a score > 0).
- Italicizes titles of questions with no answers (can be different than "unanswered").
- Changes score box tool-tip to show answer status, answer count, and question up/down vote count (even if you don't have the privilege).
- Caches sidebar status (30 minute expiration time by default) to try and reduce API calls (especially effective when re-visiting the same post).

### Console Usage:

The `SidebarAnswerStatus` object provides a console interface to certain settings and functions:

- `SidebarAnswerStatus.setCacheExpireSeconds(integer)` - Change cache expiration time. Default is 1800 seconds (30 minutes).
- `SidebarAnswerStatus.resetStats()` - Reset statistics.
- `SidebarAnswerStatus.resetAll()` - Reset everything (stats, cache, options including expiration time, etc.).
- `SidebarAnswerStatus.dumpInfo()` - Print all stored data, for debugging.

### Issues:

- API key not implemented, so uses your per-IP API quota of 300.

### Change Log:

- [1.10](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/compare/bd865a71efa796775c2fb0e11fba8ec1f799bbfc...d5a8979421c2dc6f454b9f6c44aa25879e586e55)

  - Now works in Firefox / Greasemonkey.
- [1.09](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/563d02de19ffa8381478ae2a887d748ec4041a81)

  - New console interface.
  - Ability to reset stats through console.
  - Ability to set cache expiration time through console.
- 1.08 ([+](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/d879ce12418867cbd5a25449f4be9fc8bdf7f051), [+](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/68fc7aadabd551f319301022d6606b6114c5c1ed), [+](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/618306c5e8886a6c122c8d2c47887298e2646226))

  - Warning banners now displayed when API quota is low (threshold 50 for warning, 10 for error banner).
  - Error messages now displayed in banner.
  - `window.sidebarAnswerStatusInfo()` for testing.
- [1.06](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/53a524df639763379000a47d9b9bdfe4e8fb4c3a)

  - Cleaned up stats tracking.
  - Fix border color to work on all sites.
  - Italicize text of questions with 0 answers.
  - Up/down vote counts showed on tooltips.
  - `window.sidebarAnswerStatusReset()` for testing.
- [1.04](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/23e1febd37092af1e5e57124cfdf52dd0b3cfa86)

  - Per-site cache (oops).
- [1.03](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/9f0ec7e99039e6e15ac95290a37b32d895aea6c5)

  - Cache results to try to reduce API calls.
  - Fixed a typo in quota warning.
- [1.02](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/69e329380c257678d62b7df474f1e52b52d3cb91)

  - Fixed incomplete / crappy match rules.
- [1.01](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/08bdd3a60ecec18080b26cfd1846428a3c8f070e)

  - API page size set to 100.
  - Fixed incorrect behavior when same question appeared in both "linked"
    and "related" lists.
  - Don't attempt query if no links found (e.g. on /questions/linked/*).
  - Low quota warning (< 100) in console.
- [1.00](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/a7bb7c061cb581a98b60ff56da0563e8a7511f82)

  - Initial version.

---

[Check out my other scripts.](https://stackapps.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a25350%20is%3aq%20%5bscript%5d%20)